# How to create a JButton with text on the button left and the icon separated from it on the button right

Tags: java, swing, icons, alignment, jbutton

Basically, I'm trying to make a button that has the text aligned to the left (so I'm using `setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT))` and the image on the right border of the button, far from the text.

I already tried `setHorizontalTextAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT)`, but that just makes the text go relativity to the left of the icon, which is not exactly what I want, since I needed the icon to be secluded from it.

Also, I can't make any fixed spacing because it's a series of buttons with different texts with different sizes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I can't make any fixed spacing because it's a series of buttons with different texts with different sizes.

You can dynamically change the spacing with code like:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Text on left:")
{
    @Override
    public void doLayout()
    {
        super.doLayout();

        int preferredWidth = getPreferredSize().width;
        int actualWidth = getSize().width;

        if (actualWidth != preferredWidth)
        {
            int gap = getIconTextGap() + actualWidth - preferredWidth;
            gap = Math.max(gap, UIManager.getInt("Button.iconTextGap"));
            setIconTextGap(gap);
        }
    }
};
button.setIcon( new ImageIcon("copy16.gif") );
button.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.LEADING);
```

Comment: Good use of `getIconTextGap()`. To those wondering, it `Returns the amount of space between the text and the icon displayed in this button.`

Comment: Unfortunately can't use this when the button is instantiated in generated code from a GUI builder. A workaround for that is to subclass the button and add it to the GUI builder palette, which is what I did.

Comment: I found with Java 11 and fractional display scaling (like 125%) that I had to subtract a 2 pixels fudge-factor off from `gap` otherwise an ellipsis appeared sporadically as some layouts were resized. **Update:** @MarkJeronimus 's answer seems to avoid this (and avoids the text position 'jiggling'.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a derivative of camickr's answer to allow editing in a GUI builder as well as placing it in a dynamic layout. I also removed the `UIManager.getInt("Button.iconTextGap")` so the gap will shrink to 0 if necessary.

I called it a 'Justified' button in analogy with justified text alignment (stretches a paragraph to left & right by  growing width of space characters).

```
public class JustifiedButton extends JButton {
    @Override
    public void doLayout() {
        super.doLayout();

        setIconTextGap(0);
        if (getHorizontalTextPosition() != CENTER) {
            int newGap = getSize().width - getMinimumSize().width;
            if (newGap > 0)
                setIconTextGap(newGap);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        Dimension minimumSize = super.getMinimumSize();

        if (getHorizontalTextPosition() != CENTER)
            minimumSize.width -= getIconTextGap();

        return minimumSize;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension preferredSize = super.getPreferredSize();

        if (getHorizontalTextPosition() != CENTER)
            preferredSize.width -= getIconTextGap();

        return preferredSize;
    }
}
```

This is not exactly production-ready and needs some field-testing. If I find anything, I'll edit the code.

[edit] Now works for vertical text alignments. Also simplified a bit.
[edit2] Also manipulate `getPreferredSize` to play nice with scroll pane (otherwise it keeps growing and never shrinks again)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a layout manager to your button.

```
JButton btn = new JButton();
btn.add(new JLabel(text));
btn.add(new JLabel(img));
btn.setLayout(/*best layout choice here*/);
btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x,y));
btn.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(maxX, minY));
btn.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(minX, minY)); //this one is most important when it comes to layoutmanagers
```

Sorry I can't be much help when it comes to picking out a good layout - But this will eventually get you what you want. Maybe someone else can comment on which one to use.

Comment: I was going to suggest this, but the "focus indicator" does not get painted around the components you add to the button.